# How to call performSegueWithIdentifier from within a custom class of a view that's a subview of view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I have a view controller that has a subview that uses a custom class. When I perform performSegueWithIdentifier from the context of the view controller, it works fine, however, how can I call performSegueWithIdentifier from within the context of child subview?

Comment: Can we have more details? Code?

Answer (score 3):

You can't call performSegue from an `UIView`. You can use a protocol, make the viewController implement it and set it as delegate for your custom view.

**CustomView.h**

```
@protocol CustomViewDelegate

-(void)customView:(CustomView *)view performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CustomViewDelegate> delegate;
```

**CustomView.m**

```
// This is the event on which you would like to perform the segue
-(void)didClickButton {
     [self.delegate customView:self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue"];
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // All you other stuff...

    // Set the delegate
    self.customView.delegate = self;
}

-(void)customView:(CustomView *)view performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:identifier];
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have questions

Comment: Where do you put the property id<CustomViewDelegate> delegate?

Comment: In your custom view, when the event occurs when you would like to perform the segue.